# jquery isotope not working before filter buttons are not pressedjquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

Isotope won't start when I load my page.

I have tried to use isotope (from [isotope.metafizzy.co](http://isotope.metafizzy.co)) with filtering buttons.

Here is my code of HTML and JS:

```
<div class="scroll-pane">   
    <div id="container" class="isotope">
         <div class="isotope-item box-item size1 group1"> 
             <img width="190" height="130" src="..." class="wp-post-image" />
             <a href="..." class="projDescription">Some text here</a>
          </div>    
         <div class="isotope-item box-item size1 group1 group2"> ... </div> 
         <div class="isotope-item box-item size3 group1"> ... </div>    
         ..
   </div>
</div>

<ul id="filters">
    <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="selected">Show all</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".group1">Kategorija1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".group2">Kategorija2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".group3">Kategorija3</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    jQuery('#isotope_content').isotope({        
      layoutMode: 'masonryHorizontal',
        masonryHorizontal: {
            rowHeight: 132
        }
    });
    jQuery("ul#filters li a").click(function() {
      jQuery("ul#filters li a").not(this).removeClass("selected");
      jQuery(this).toggleClass("selected");
    });

    jQuery(".box-item").hover(function(){
        jQuery(this).children(".projDescription").stop().fadeTo(350,0.9)},
        function(){
            jQuery(this).children(".projDescription").stop().fadeTo(350,0)
        }
    );

    jQuery('#filters a').click(function(){
      var selector = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter');
      jQuery('#container').isotope({ 
        filter: selector 
      });
      return false;
    });    
});
```

The problem is that when page loads first time then isotope is not working, nothing happens with images. If I press any of filter buttons (Show All or any other) then it works.

I cannot reproduce this problem withing JsFiddle. THe only way to see this it online - http://dev.metolat.lv/

Website loads without isotope functioning, but after pressing "Show All" it reorders images as expected.

Just a note - I am using Wordpress to create this page, but I do not use any plugin for isotope, instead I am including it directly.

I believe that this could be something with script and image loading order, but I could not resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see there is no element with id of `isotope_content` which you feed to isotope at initialization. There is however a div `content` which you use in your filters click handlers -- and it works. So change `isotope_content` to `content` and it should work.

BTW. `load` is a deprecated jQuery method as of ( [1.8](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) ). If you'd be having image problems you can also look into isotope author's other plugin called [imagesLoaded](http://desandro.github.io/imagesloaded/) (it should be bundled with isotope anyway).

Comment: Shouldn't this be "change isotope_content to container?